# Angular 4 server prerendering in ASP.NET Core is so slow

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering

I have an asp.net core angular4 project with server side rendering, the problem that this project load **sooo slowly** on local and even on prod, I tried to minimize main-client.js but nothing changed.

I learned that server side rendering is so fast when loading the first page. 
So is there a way to make the loading more faster. or do I remove the server side rendering and work with a node server?

Comment: I have same issue it's very slow and take about 20's time.